# STUCK on logo after installing cwm recovery ,samsung sl gt-i9003

Tags: clockworkmod-recovery, 2.3.3-gingerbread

I am using a **Samsung SL GT-i9003**.

After installing CWM recovery I am stuck on the logo screen, and my external sd card is also not showing in the recovery mode.

But I am able to enter download mode and CWM recovery mode (by amit.bigiria v 5.0.2.8)

How can I get my device back to normal mode?

Answer (score 0):

Flash Stock ROM for Samsung SL GT-i9003 in ODIN.

Here are some Stock ROMs: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1004647